# query wikidata using property and itemlabel

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Hi i'm trying to work with `wikidata` in order to enrich text data for a classification nlp task, but i have zero knowledge and i'm running out of time.

What I want to query in wikidata:

> Let's say I'd like to know that Mercedes-Benz is part of the
>   automotive industry.

I'd like to give as a filtering condition the `itemLabel` Mercedes-benz:

I've tried Something like:

```
#All items with a property
# Sample to query all values of a property
# Property talk pages on Wikidata include basic queries adapted to each property
SELECT
  ?item ?itemLabel
  ?value ?valueLabel
# valueLabel is only useful for properties with item-datatype
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P452 ?itemLabel 
  FILTER(CONTAINS(LCASE(?itemLabel), "Mercedes-benz"@en))    
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
# remove or change limit for more results
LIMIT 10
```

which is returning an empty results.
Help?

Thanks

Comment: because `?itemLabel` is a special variable bound to the result after everything is done by a special SERVICE. This is not SPARQL standard, thus, it does not work

Comment: the correct way and the SPARQL way is to write `?item rdfs:label "Mercedes-Benz"@en .   `

Comment: I also don't get why you do `?item wdt:P452 ?itemLabel ` - it binds and industry to the item, but then you won't make use of the label SERVICE. It should be `?item wdt:P452 ?value `

Comment: Moreover, in `FILTER(CONTAINS(LCASE(?itemLabel), "Mercedes-benz"@en))` you'd make the first value lower case, but your second value contains upper-case chars. Do you think this makes sense? Here with filters (though poor performance of course): `SELECT
  ?item ?itemLabel
  ?value ?valueLabel
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P452 ?value .
  ?item rdfs:label ?label    
  FILTER(lang(?label) = 'en' && CONTAINS(LCASE(STR(?label)), LCASE("Mercedes-benz")))
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
LIMIT 10`

Comment: here with the more efficient search feature: `SELECT
  ?item ?itemLabel
  ?value ?valueLabel

WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P452 ?value .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi { bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch" .
   bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" .
   bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "Mercedes-benz" .
   bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en" .
  ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item .
   ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true . } 
}

ORDER BY ASC(?num)
LIMIT 10`

Comment: that's what I was looking for. I'm sorry if my question was kind of a mess.